# In statement picking up spaces

Tags: sql, case-statement

I have a field called datatype that I am trying to filter on.  If the value equals LOINC then I want a 1, if it does not equal LOINC then I want a zero.  The challenge that I am having is that sometimes the word LOINC has an extra space at the end of it.  Since I am doing this check to evaluate the validity of a file, if there is the word LOINC  and then a space, I need it to error out.
When I tried to write the this as

```
when Datatype = 'LOINC' then 1 else 0 end as Test1
```

It came back with 1's for the cases where LOINC had extra spaces at the end of it and when LOINC did not.
LOINC is one value of many that I am looking at, I can get around this by adding a different validation process but I would rather not if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL ignores trailing blanks for comparison. In most cases you can simply switch to `LIKE` instead (which doesn't ignore trailing blanks):

```
when Datatype LIKE 'LOINC' then 1 else 0 end as Test1
```

Answer (score 0):

RTRIM(str) - RTRIM removes all white spaces at the end of the string.
SELECT TRIM('   God   '); and output will be = 'God'
TRIM - it removes LEADING, TRAILING, or BOTH white spaces.
In your case the query should be

```
when RTRIM(Datatype) = 'LOINC' then 1 else 0 end as Test1
```

But i suggest trim, as it will remove blank spaces from leading and trailing

```
when TRIM(Datatype) = 'LOINC' then 1 else 0 end as Test1
```